# how to change timeout in speechRecognizer ContinuousRecognitionSession

Tags: c#

I am experimenting with SpeechRecognizer ContinuousRecognitionSession. If I do not talk for more than 20 seconds approximately SpeechRecognizer ContinuousRecognitionSession times out.

I keep getting SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.TimeoutExceeded status in SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed event.

I would like to change the default timeout. I am not sure where I would do it. I tried the following code

```
speechRecognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
speechRecognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
speechRecognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.AutoStopSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
```

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :`recognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`